# changing user inputed date and time to a unix timestamp

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, strptime

I have a user input where the user inputs time and date as '9.30am' and '01/02/2012'. I am trying to convert this to a unix timestamp to aid ordering when dragging the data back out of the database but strptime() is confusing me as I am unsure as to whether this is actually returning a unix timestamp that I need.

Comment: Use `mktime()` or `strtotime()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP's built-in DateTime class...

```
$objDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:ia d/m/Y', '9:30am 1/2/2012');
$timestamp = $objDate->getTimestamp();
```

...returns a Unix timestamp.

Documentation:

1. [PHP DateTime Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

   a. [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

   b. [DateTime::getTimestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)

To add your variables, use it like so...

```
$objDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:ia d/m/Y', "$time $date");
$timestamp = $objDate->getTimestamp();
```

Or...

```
$time_date = sprintf("%s %s", $time, $date); // concatenates into a single var
$objDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:ia d/m/Y', $time_date);
$timestamp = $objDate->getTimestamp();
```

**Note:** Make sure that your variables conform with the following...

`$time` = hh:mm (and "am" or "pm" is appended)

`$date` = dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Can't seem to get this working - whenever I add variables it just stalls the script ie: ('H:ia d/m/Y', '$time $date') or ('H:ia d/m/Y', $time $date). What is the correct syntax ?

Comment: @Sideshow See my edit above. PHP allows for variables to be inserted in double quotes (in most cases), so you can drop your variables into a string as the second parameter (or create a var containing `time` and `date`). Make sure you use double quotes; single quotes **will not work**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)


 PHP.net Example:

```
echo strtotime("now"), "\n";
echo strtotime("10 September 2000"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 day"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds"), "\n";
echo strtotime("next Thursday"), "\n";
echo strtotime("last Monday"), "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use strtotime()

Call it by putting in your variables.

strtotime("9.30 1/2/2012");

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:ia d/m/Y' '9:30am 1/2/2012');
$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
```

Is what you are looking for. http://www.php.net/datetime